# Ignore Returned Value

Tags: lua

```
local meshId = message:sub(message, message:find(message, "/hat%s%d"), message:find(message, "/hat %d+"))
```

The `message:find()` returns two values; the **first** character and the **last** character.  How would I make it only return the **last character**?

Answer (score 0):

If a function returns more than one parameter, you can use `select(2, functioncall())` to get the second parameter. For example:

```
function returntwo() return "first", "second" end
print(select(2, returntwo())) -- prints "second"
```

In the case in question, you'd use it as `local meshId = message:sub(message, select(2, message:find(message, "/hat%s%d")), select(2, message:find(message, "/hat %d+")))`

Comment: @Oka Functions in non-final locations are adjusted to single return values. (Wrapping a function-call, etc. in parentheses will also do this.) So in the OPs call the `:find` call cannot return more than one value so the use of `select` will work as intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but how would I apply it specifically to this?  I'm a newbie to lua, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, I think solution. just second prameter return

```
function returnTwo(...)
    local a, b = message:find(...)
    return b
end
```

wrap message:find function and return second value

How about?

Comment: Like this?  local a, b = message:find(" ")
  
  local meshId = message:sub(6, b - 1)
  local textureId = message:sub(b + 1, message:len())

Comment: I don't know what the message object, Is string class?, same lua default string function?